# SQL query to find max, min when data changed

Tags: sql, sql-server

need sql select min(date),max(date)when change stat for each code
 iam try this query it work well with where condition but he give me wrong data
without condition

```
select x.code,x.stat,x.grp, min(date) as min_date, max(date) as max_date
from (
    select code,stat,date ,
          row_number() over (order by date)- row_number() over (partition by stat order by date) as grp
    from  c 
     where code='1')  X
   group by code,stat,grp
   order by min(date)
```

my table

```
code     stat     date
1         s       01/01/2012
1         s       02/01/2012
1         i       03/01/2012
1         s       04/01/2012
2         a       01/01/2012
2         a       02/01/2012
```

need this result

```
code     stat     min date     max date
1         s       01/01/2012  02/01/2012
1         i       03/01/2012  03/01/2012
1         s       04/01/2012  04/01/2012
2         a       01/01/2012  02/01/2012
```

Comment: Which version of sql server you are using ?

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is basically correct except for the missing `partition by`:

```
select c.code, c.stat, c.grp,
       min(c.date) as min_date, max(c.date) as max_date
from (select c.*
             row_number() over (partition by c.code order by c.date) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by c.code, c.stat order by date) as seqnum_d
      from c 
     ) c
group by c.code, c.stat, c.grp
order by min(c.date);
```